# How to disprove $n^3 = \Omega(9^{\log_2(n)})$

Tags: asymptotics

I'm having trouble to disprove the following statement:

$$n^3 = \Omega(9^{\log_2(n)})$$

I'm pretty sure that the claim is false but I'm struggling to falsify it in a formal way. I tried to calculate 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^3}{9^{\log_2(n)}}$$

by using L'Hopital's rule in order to apply the limit rule, but this leads to very 'ugly' terms.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Can you figure out how to write $n^3$ in the form $C^{\log_2(n)}$ for some $C$? (Alternately, how to write $9^{\log_2(n)}$ in the form $n^D$ for some $D$)

Comment: Ah, you mean like $n^3 = 2 ^{log_2(n^3)}$ ?                                              
But how can we advance from here?

Comment: Rewriting $9^{\log_2n}$ as $n^a$ for some given $a$ might be the most direct approach. Can you do that?

Comment: Sorry, I can't find a way to do that. Could you give me a hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n^3 =?\  \Omega(9^{\log_2(n)})
$

$9^{\log_2(n)}
=e^{\ln 9\cdot \ln n/\ln 2}
=n^{\ln 9/\ln 2}
$.

Since
$\ln 8/\ln 2 = 3$,
$\ln 9/\ln 2
\gt 3$
so
$\dfrac{n^3}{9^{\log_2(n)}}
=n^{3-\ln 9/\ln 2}
\to 0
$
as $n \to \infty$.

Note that
$\ln 9/\ln 2
\approx 3.169925$
so that
$\dfrac{n^3}{9^{\log_2(n)}}
\approx \dfrac1{n^{0.1669925}}
$.